# How to count login hours between logging on and off multiple times in a day in sql

Tags: sql, datetime, datediff

I am a beginner at SQL. I have rows for logon and log off where I can see the time between each log on and log off. I would like to count how many hours a user was logged on.

```
select oneAA.DT, oneAA.first_name, oneAA.surname, oneAA.time, oneAA.name, oneAA.incID,  --now add the hours 
twoAA.time, twoAA.name, twoAA.incID,
    convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, oneAA.time, twoAA.time)/3600)+ ' hr '+
    convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, oneAA.time, twoAA.time)%3600/60)+' min '+
    convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, oneAA.time, twoAA.time)%60))+ ' sec' as logOn_time 
--into #MatthewTime
from #Matthews oneAA
inner join #Matthews twoAA on twoAA.incID = oneAA.incID +1
where oneAA.name = 'AcdAgentLoggedOnEvent'
```

and this is what I get as a result:

```
DT  first_name  surname time    name    incID   time    name    incID   logOn_time
2015-01-05  Matthews    Seforo  07:59:42    AcdAgentLoggedOnEvent   1   08:57:19    AcdAgentLoggedOffEvent  2   0 hr 57 min 37 sec
2015-01-05  Matthews    Seforo  08:57:54    AcdAgentLoggedOnEvent   3   10:08:14    AcdAgentLoggedOffEvent  4   1 hr 10 min 20 sec
2015-01-05  Matthews    Seforo  10:08:15    AcdAgentLoggedOnEvent   5   10:14:12    AcdAgentLoggedOffEvent  6   0 hr 5 min 57 sec
2015-01-05  Matthews    Seforo  10:27:08    AcdAgentLoggedOnEvent   7   10:33:17    AcdAgentLoggedOffEvent  8   0 hr 6 min 9 sec
2015-01-05  Matthews    Seforo  10:34:48    AcdAgentLoggedOnEvent   9   11:01:02    AcdAgentLoggedOffEvent  10  0 hr 26 min 14 sec
2015-01-05  Matthews    Seforo  12:04:15    AcdAgentLoggedOnEvent   11  13:29:14    AcdAgentLoggedOffEvent  12  1 hr 24 min 59 sec
2015-01-05  Matthews    Seforo  13:29:16    AcdAgentLoggedOnEvent   13  14:32:13    AcdAgentLoggedOffEvent  14  1 hr 2 min 57 sec
2015-01-05  Matthews    Seforo  14:32:45    AcdAgentLoggedOnEvent   15  16:32:40    AcdAgentLoggedOffEvent  16  1 hr 59 min 55 sec
2015-01-05  Matthews    Seforo  16:32:42    AcdAgentLoggedOnEvent   17  17:03:22    AcdAgentLoggedOffEvent  18  0 hr 30 min 40 sec
```

What I want is to add the last column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what's the expected output if someone is logged on over midnight?

Comment: Tag your post with appropriate RDBMS tag.

Comment: This is for work hours. But if someone is logged on, I still want to see it then in the end add all the hours that user was logged on. I might be going at it the wrong way but I have been trying different approaches as you can see with the //commented temp table

Comment: There are many cases to consider like what if they log on twice? log off twice? log off and back on within 5 minutes? 10 minutes? 6 hours? Once you dig into your data you will find all these cases and will need to consider them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested this but I think you may be looking for something like this (You will need to make sure your Select is ordered in the same manner i.e. by DT and Surname, firstname.

```
convert(varchar(5),SUM(DateDiff(s, oneAA.time, twoAA.time)) Over (Partition by oneAA.surname, oneAA.first_name order by oneAA.DT) /3600) + ' hr '+
convert(varchar(5),SUM(DateDiff(s, oneAA.time, twoAA.time)) Over (Partition by oneAA.surname, oneAA.first_name order by oneAA.DT) % 3600/60)+' min '+
convert(varchar(5),SUM(DateDiff(s, oneAA.time, twoAA.time)) Over (Partition by oneAA.surname, oneAA.first_name order by oneAA.DT) %60)+ ' sec' as Overall_logOn_time
```

Just to add to this, you should really be doing your datediff's by datetime rather than just time to accommodate any times past midnight.

Comment: It worked thanks but I had to remove the order by and I am happy. You are a hero. Thanks